# How to install Blackberry 10 Native(QT, C/C++) on Windows Machine

Tags: qt, blackberry, installation, blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator

I am trying to install Blackberry 10 Native in my Windows 7 Machine, but somehow i am unable to install it properly, so please any one can guide me how can i install Blackberry 10 in my Windows 7 Machine.

I already downloaded **Momentics IDE** and also i have followed the instruction from this link

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/getting_started/setting_up.html

One more thing is that i don't have Blackberry device so i have to run mt application on simulator.

Please I just want brief guidance about how to setup all environment related to run `Blackberry 10` on my Windows Machine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Momentics installed without an issue, and simulator is the problem. You need VMware Player or some other virtual machine. You simply

- Download and install [VMware Player (Free for personal use)](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_player/6_0)
- in Momentics: where the "`on:`" choose "`Add new target`", click "`Simulator`", `Install a new simulator` and choose the version you want.
- Once installed Launch simulator, go to `Settings` (in the simulator), `Security and Privacy`, `Turn on development mode` (you need to create password for this). I'm not 100% you need to turn on development mode on simulator but I do it anyway
- Go back to Momentics (under Add new target), click `Properties`, enter password you used in simulator and click `Connect`.

Another thing that might be useful. You don't need signing keys on a simulator, but you do if you want to try on a real device. I hope you tried Momentics 2.1 beta, it's slightly better

Comment: Thank you @Bojan Kogoj, I will try this and let you know what happens... Thank you for this brief answer.